# I want "continue..." text when sub report will overflow to new page

Tags: jasper-reports

I think, this should be a feature, when the subreport detail band overflow to the next page, that "...continued" or something should came, but I can't able to solve that issue and I have tried to find out, if there is any solution, but nothing works..

Can any one have a better idea, how to get the solution?

Comment: What have been you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

The "normal" way to do is:

In **subreport** put the text in the `detail` band (if it is not there already), if text without datasource (just pass a `new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource(1)` to the subreport so that `detail` band is displayed one.

> Having text in `detail` band allows us to use the `pageFooter` band, note
>   `title` band and `summary` band overflows on new page without the
>   `pageFooter`. You can also use the `summary` band but then you need to set attribute `isSummaryWithPageHeaderAndFooter="true"` on `jasperReport` tag.

In **subreport** add the a `pageFooterBand` with your text

es.

```
<pageFooter>
    <band height="50">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="446" y="18" width="100" height="20" uuid="efa2e741-c546-4261-bdb7-a4b211212f17"/>
            <text><![CDATA[...continued]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</pageFooter>
```

This will display the text "...continued" on every subreport page, since we like to avoid it on last page add empty `lastPageFooter`

```
<lastPageFooter>
    <band height="50"/>
</lastPageFooter>
```