# How can I export report to PDF/A-1a, PDF/A-1b?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, pdf-generation, export-to-pdf, pdfa

*Generating PDF/A in jasper-report, contains numerous pitfalls and is not supported in some versions of jasper-report. This is why I have decided to pass this **Q**uestion-**A**nswer post, indicating the steps and library version necessary to export a simple report with a graph to PDF/A*

**Sample data** (usersRep.csv)

```
+----------------+--------+
|      User      |  Rep   |
+----------------+--------+
| Jon Skeet      | 854503 |
| Darin Dimitrov | 652133 |
| BalusC         | 639753 |
| Hans Passant   | 616871 |
| Me             |   5640 |
+----------------+--------+
```

**Sample jrxml** (reputation.jrxml)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="reputation" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="a88bd694-4f90-41fc-84d0-002b90b2d73e">
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="User" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Rep" class="java.lang.Long"/>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="9e7b5f50-5795-4c95-a122-f14f2e3f9366"/>
                <box leftPadding="3" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="3">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Double"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[User]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="4a6f0a2a-d9b5-4e74-a9e8-0f965336f2bf"/>
                <box leftPadding="3" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="3">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Double"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Reputation]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="8ff583b9-88dc-4726-85e1-16d79de78095"/>
                <box leftPadding="3" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="3">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{User}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="ebd33b2f-7297-41c2-9dc7-78ff472890c4"/>
                <box leftPadding="3" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="3">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Rep}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="140">
            <pieChart>
                <chart isShowLegend="false">
                    <reportElement x="225" y="-670" width="320" height="140" uuid="23bd26a6-04a4-406f-8a1a-5e1b260cb75d"/>
                    <chartTitle/>
                    <chartSubtitle/>
                    <chartLegend/>
                </chart>
                <pieDataset>
                    <keyExpression><![CDATA[$F{User}]]></keyExpression>
                    <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{Rep}]]></valueExpression>
                </pieDataset>
                <piePlot>
                    <plot/>
                    <itemLabel/>
                </piePlot>
            </pieChart>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

**Java code to export to PDF** (reputation.pdf)

```java
JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("reputation.jrxml");
JRCsvDataSource datasource = new JRCsvDataSource("usersRep.csv");
datasource.setFieldDelimiter(';');
datasource.setUseFirstRowAsHeader(true);

JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, new HashMap<String, Object>(),datasource);

JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput("reputation.pdf"));
SimplePdfExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
configuration.setMetadataAuthor("Me and only me");
exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
exporter.exportReport();
```

This export the report to a pdf, what do I need to do to generate a PDF/A-1a?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

JasperReports Library 4.1.2.3 or higher [is needed](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/pdf-support-jasperreports-library) (with discontinued support in 6.0.0 see `NullPointerException` at the end).

These steps are need to generate a PDF/A, they can be achieved both by java code or by setting jrxml `property` to root tag (jasper-server support). I will show both but **only one method is necessary**.

#Set PDF/A Conformance

**java**

```java
configuration.setPdfaConformance(PdfaConformanceEnum.PDFA_1A); // or PdfaConformanceEnum.PDFA_1B
```

**jrxml**

```xml
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdfa.conformance" value="pdfa1a" />
```

#Set [ICC Profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICC_profile)

> to avoid `JRPdfaIccProfileNotFoundException: The ICC profile is not available to the JVM`

**java**

```java
configuration.setIccProfilePath("srgb.icc");
```

**jrxml**

```xml
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdfa.icc.profile.path" value="srgb.icc" />
```

#Embed all font used in reports, using [font-extensions](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/)

If you still have error

```java
com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfXConformanceException: All the fonts must be embedded. This one isn't: Helvetica
```

include a **default style** in the jrxml indicating `fontName` that is included in font extension, example

```xml
<style name="default" isDefault="true" fontName="DejaVu Sans"/>
```

#Remove transparent objects and layers (Optional Content Groups) they are [not allowed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF/A)

> to avoid `PdfXConformanceException: Transparency is not allowed`

In example the chart element must be `Opaque` and to avoid transparency on the labels you can implement a [JRChartCustomizer](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRChartCustomizer.html)

```java
public class NoTransparencyCustomizer implements JRChartCustomizer{
    @Override
    public void customize(JFreeChart chart, JRChart jrchart) {
        PiePlot plot = (PiePlot) chart.getPlot();
        plot.setLabelShadowPaint(Color.GRAY);       
    }
}
```

#Set Tagged and tag language (unnecessary for PDF/A-1b)

**java**

```java
configuration.setTagged(true);
configuration.setTagLanguage("en-us");
```

**jrxml**

```xml
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tagged" value="true" />
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.language" value="en-us"/>
```

#Result

This is the result implementing the above, switching `fontName` to `DejaVu Sans` and using the bundled `jasperreports-fonts.jar` as font-extension. It has been validated successfully on [pdf-tools](http://www.pdf-tools.com/pdf/validate-pdfa-online.aspx) for both PDF/A-1a and PDF/A-1b

[image: Result]

*No piece of the cake for me*

**XMP property is not synchronized with the document information**

```xml
Validating file "reputation.pdf" for conformance level pdfa-1a
dc:description/*[0] :: Missing language qualifier.
dc:title/*[0] :: Missing language qualifier.
The XMP property 'dc:title' is not synchronized with the document information entry 'Title'.
The XMP property 'dc:description' is not synchronized with the document information entry 'Subject'.
```

This error comes from using older jasper-reports library <6.2.0 when you set metadata title or subject in configuration.

```xml
configuration.setMetadataTitle("Title");
configuration.setMetadataSubject("Subject");
```

The solution is to remove these or update jasper-reports to versione 6.2.0 or above see [PDF/A_1A XMP Metadata validation fails if title and/or subject are set](https://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-library/issues/5061) for more information

**Discontinued support**
In jasper report version 6.0.0 a `NullPointerException at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.internal.PdfA1Checker.checkPdfObject` was always thrown. This has been solved in 6.0.4 and above see [Jasper report tracker](http://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-library/issues/3988).

Comment: Great explanations, thanks! Any idea if PDF/A-2 is being supported by now? Support for PDF/A-1a and 1b came first in 2011, but then iText 2.17 did not support PDF/A-2, therefore it could not be supported by Jasperreports.

Comment: @alainlompo Current versione 6.20, https://appdoc.app/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports/6.20.0/net/sf/jasperreports/export/type/PdfaConformanceEnum.html does not seem to support it as you seem to know jasper is using an old version of itext 2.1.7.js10 (due to licenze issues) so I guess it will not be trivial for them to support also PDF/A-2