# How to remove box around label in piechart?

Tags: jasper-reports, jfreechart, pie-chart

Does anyone know how to remove the box/border around label in jasperreport piechart?  What do I need to include in the .jrxml file so that the label displayed with no border.

Comment: Are you asking about simple pie-chart or about highcharts?

Comment: This is pie3DChart

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a [`JRChartCustomizer`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRChartCustomizer.html), setting `labelOutlinePaint` and `labelShadowPaint` to `null` in plot

### Example

**Java customizer**

```
public class NoLabelCustomizer implements JRChartCustomizer{
    @Override
    public void customize(JFreeChart chart, JRChart jrchart) {
        PiePlot plot = (PiePlot) chart.getPlot();
         plot.setLabelOutlinePaint(null);
         plot.setLabelShadowPaint(null);    
    }
}
```

**jrxml**

```
<pie3DChart>
    <chart isShowLegend="false" customizerClass="NoLabelCustomizer">
            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="225" y="0" width="320" height="140" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="23bd26a6-04a4-406f-8a1a-5e1b260cb75d"/>
            <chartTitle/>
            <chartSubtitle/>
            <chartLegend/>
            <anchorNameExpression><![CDATA["Graph"]]></anchorNameExpression>
            <hyperlinkTooltipExpression><![CDATA["Graph"]]></hyperlinkTooltipExpression>
    </chart>
    <pieDataset>
            <keyExpression><![CDATA[$F{User}]]></keyExpression>
            <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{Rep}]]></valueExpression>
    </pieDataset>
    <pie3DPlot isShowLabels="true">
            <plot/>
            <itemLabel/>
    </pie3DPlot>
</pie3DChart>
```

> Note the `customizerClass="NoLabelCustomizer"` on the chart tag

**Output** (using datasource from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36306170/how-can-i-export-report-to-pdf-a-1a-pdf-a-1b))

[image: Result]