# Using JasperReports to make a PDF file accessible

Tags: java, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I am trying to make a PDF file accessible, and I am using Adobe Acrobat to check for accessibility.

[image]

I am using JasperReports **version 6.3.1**.

1. How do I set the primary language and title? I used the following code to add a title, but it did not work. What do I need to add in the JRXML file?

   ```
   JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
   exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.METADATA_TITLE, "Invoice");
   ```
2. How do I set the tab order for elements on a page (table, text fields, etc.)?

Comment: Your `METADATA_TITLE` seems correct (there is also `PROPERTY_DISPLAY_METADATA_TITLE` that you can try to set to true, this will add a viewer preference), for the tab order as far as I can see it's always default [PdfName.S](https://github.com/Jaspersoft/jasperreports/blob/master/jasperreports/src/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JRPdfExporter.java#L779), that is "use document structure".

Comment: Note: You are using deprecated code see for example this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36306170/5292302) how to use the new `SimplePdfExporterConfiguration`.