# How to print a text field on first line of the second column of a page?

Tags: jasper-reports, multiple-columns

I have a page with two columns, which is a table of contents page, and I want to print bookmarks according to their level value on first and second column. The problem is although the printing order is set to `vertical`, when jasper finishes the first column it won't start from the beginning of the second column, but it writes at the end of the column.

[image: Is situation] As you can see on the picture, I need to have the sentence with yellow square at the beginning of the second column.

**jrxml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.4.0.final using JasperReports     Library version 6.4.1  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4_Landscape" columnCount="2" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="400" columnSpacing="2" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="b0cd6df7-ceab-4f93-aff6-668d7c75ce9b">
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
<parameter name="resourcePath" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[""]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="Einrichtungspseudonym" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["Einrichtungspseudonym"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="reportPart" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["reportPart"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<queryString language="SQL">
    <![CDATA[]]>
</queryString>
<field name="level" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<field name="label" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="pageIndex" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</background>
<pageHeader>
    <band height="50" splitType="Stretch">
        <frame>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="702" height="50" backcolor="rgba(227, 218, 218, 0.46666667)" uuid="6ca5e261-9531-43ef-80ed-828dc6b4524f"/>
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement x="0" y="18" width="702" height="17" forecolor="#A1A1A1" backcolor="#D9D9D9" uuid="54beea72-4243-48ea-856e-29d9da8a0431">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="cm"/>
                </reportElement>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </rectangle>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement style="Kopfzeile" x="2" y="0" width="330" height="50" uuid="f9f8c8d7-253c-46bd-b8ab-fe737db7070d"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Tabellen- und Abbildungsverzeichnis"]]></textFieldExpression>
                <anchorNameExpression><![CDATA["Tabellen- und Abbildungsverzeichnis"]]></anchorNameExpression>
            </textField>
            <image>
                <reportElement x="632" y="0" width="70" height="50" uuid="16558eec-b7b6-4fc4-b6ea-6fb3ff4b5e2f"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{resourcePath}+"Logo_vertical_RGB.png"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
        </frame>
    </band>
</pageHeader>
<columnHeader>
    <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement style="Kapitelüberschrift" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="0" width="394" height="20" uuid="2d7b27c2-91b1-4d62-97b6-ca0d4dd1c099"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Tabellen- und Abbildungsverzechnis"]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement style="Kapitelüberschrift" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="412" y="0" width="388" height="20" uuid="edc812df-deaa-4511-9b46-1c5c963b31a9"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Abbildungen der Ergebniszusammenfassung"]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="113" splitType="Stretch">
        <frame>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="411" y="3" width="340" height="17" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="517ee347-d843-43d4-9855-b4c1cc6b490c">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{level}  == 21]]></printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement stretchType="ContainerHeight" x="0" y="0" width="11" height="17" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" forecolor="#E8A435" backcolor="#FCCF3A" uuid="3a9abeb8-b2a9-4650-b034-9eb7815e7f09">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="cm"/>
                </reportElement>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </rectangle>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" hyperlinkType="LocalAnchor">
                <reportElement style="Standard" x="20" y="0" width="290" height="17" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="f96bf175-4d0f-494f-8eb6-ac9270a53ec5"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{label}]]></textFieldExpression>
                <hyperlinkAnchorExpression><![CDATA[$F{label}]]></hyperlinkAnchorExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement key="" style="Standard" x="310" y="0" width="30" height="17" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="eadc2beb-1873-44a7-b8ca-26815fc64601"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER} + $F{pageIndex} + 4]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </frame>
        <frame>
            <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="3" width="351" height="110" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="f7f28f9f-f011-42c5-b10b-68986a90ce92">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.FreeLayout"/>
            </reportElement>
            <frame>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="351" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="870d4b8e-dcf2-40dc-8c1a-4e77b878b898">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{level} == 31]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" hyperlinkType="LocalAnchor">
                    <reportElement style="Standard_mit_html" mode="Transparent" x="20" y="0" width="301" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="6fee51d3-a833-48e2-8eba-72228aeb58d7">
                        <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Left" markup="styled"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{label}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    <hyperlinkAnchorExpression><![CDATA[$F{label}]]></hyperlinkAnchorExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement style="Standard" x="321" y="0" width="30" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="5868d8c8-7eb1-495b-b848-a193237679a2">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="cm"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[6]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <rectangle>
                    <reportElement stretchType="ContainerHeight" x="0" y="0" width="11" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" forecolor="#5A49F2" backcolor="#783AFC" uuid="f52cbdd2-131c-4726-9945-dea36bb1275c">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="cm"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <graphicElement>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    </graphicElement>
                </rectangle>
            </frame>
            <frame>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="18" width="351" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="429e6789-ec18-4e23-b84a-ddff038ddf31">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{level} == 32]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" hyperlinkType="LocalAnchor">
                    <reportElement style="Standard_mit_html" mode="Transparent" x="20" y="8" width="301" height="10" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="3e6b8d9c-94e8-47eb-b1ca-926607daf19e">
                        <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Left" markup="styled"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{label}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    <hyperlinkAnchorExpression><![CDATA[$F{label}]]></hyperlinkAnchorExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement style="Standard" x="321" y="8" width="30" height="10" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="45cb3231-65b2-4b03-8387-cb67d968d4de">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="cm"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[6]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <rectangle>
                    <reportElement stretchType="ContainerHeight" x="0" y="8" width="11" height="10" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" forecolor="#1BAEF7" backcolor="#56B4FC" uuid="8f7cd5e1-539e-455d-992d-7754d5b50aef">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="cm"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <graphicElement>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    </graphicElement>
                </rectangle>
            </frame>
        </frame>
    </band>
</detail>
<pageFooter>
    <band height="31" splitType="Stretch">
        <frame>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="802" height="31" uuid="99847b36-f679-406b-b7c6-44151acc24e4">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.HorizontalRowLayout"/>
            </reportElement>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement style="Fußzeile 8,5pt" x="0" y="0" width="394" height="31" uuid="5d388cd5-181d-48b6-981a-9034f2ca3edf"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["© report: Quartalsbericht "+$P{reportPart}+" für Einrichtung "+$P{Einrichtungspseudonym}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" evaluationTime="Master">
                <reportElement style="Fußzeile 8,5pt" x="408" y="0" width="394" height="31" uuid="4efe47cc-4b4c-415a-9c38-1cfabd3c347d">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="cm"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{MASTER_CURRENT_PAGE} != null ? $V{MASTER_CURRENT_PAGE}+"/"+$V{MASTER_TOTAL_PAGES} : $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </frame>
    </band>
</pageFooter>
```

I tried another approach as well, in which I just created a page with single column, then put the fields in two frames, one on the left side and the other one on the write side of the page. But the result is just same as previous approach.
Code for the single column page:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Abbildungsverzeichnis" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="702" leftMargin="70" rightMargin="70" topMargin="42" bottomMargin="42" whenResourceMissingType="Empty" uuid="6e74177b-d551-4a75-ae51-6cdde3f284ce">
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit." value="cm"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.print.create.bookmarks" value="false"/>
<template><![CDATA[$P{resourcePath}+"styles.jrtx"]]></template>
<parameter name="resourcePath" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[""]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="Einrichtungspseudonym" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["Einrichtungspseudonym"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="Berichtsquartal" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["Berichtsquartal"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<queryString language="XPath">
    <![CDATA[/QSDialyse2018QuartalsberichtLe]]>
</queryString>
<field name="level" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<field name="label" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="pageIndex" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</background>
<pageHeader>
    <band height="50">
        <frame>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="702" height="50" backcolor="rgba(227, 218, 218, 0.46666667)" uuid="06038290-751d-4458-807d-96a3e51e7d1d"/>
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement x="0" y="18" width="702" height="17" forecolor="#A1A1A1" backcolor="#D9D9D9" uuid="ca066fcc-d491-4f4b-aa09-17ae01773098">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="cm"/>
                </reportElement>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </rectangle>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement style="Kopfzeile" x="2" y="0" width="330" height="50" uuid="4a0983f4-b41e-4828-a73d-7e285cb31887"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Tabellen- und Abbildungsverzeichnis"]]></textFieldExpression>
                <anchorNameExpression><![CDATA["Tabellen- und Abbildungsverzeichnis"]]></anchorNameExpression>
            </textField>
        </frame>
    </band>
</pageHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="110" splitType="Stretch">
        <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.FreeLayout"/>
        <frame>
            <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="0" width="351" height="110" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="c5f75321-dadb-4152-acab-6208ed6878de">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.FreeLayout"/>
            </reportElement>
            <frame>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="0" width="351" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="a3604c51-5a78-4577-b0f8-2cc19c403996">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{level} == 31]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" hyperlinkType="LocalAnchor">
                    <reportElement style="Standard_mit_html" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" mode="Transparent" x="20" y="0" width="301" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="379fcff2-021d-4761-a89a-eeb772723b1b">
                        <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Left" markup="styled"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{label}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    <hyperlinkAnchorExpression><![CDATA[$F{label}]]></hyperlinkAnchorExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement style="Standard" x="321" y="0" width="30" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="207a4316-1f91-4886-91f9-9a86c788a83f">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="cm"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER} + $F{pageIndex} + 4]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <rectangle>
                    <reportElement stretchType="ContainerHeight" x="0" y="0" width="11" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" forecolor="#5A49F2" backcolor="#783AFC" uuid="f9a97c9f-4bc7-4ede-b082-d39a697f10ec">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="cm"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <graphicElement>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    </graphicElement>
                </rectangle>
            </frame>
            <frame>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="18" width="351" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="c01291d6-8266-4368-bd93-8a9dc0b52770">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{level} == 32]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" hyperlinkType="LocalAnchor">
                    <reportElement style="Standard_mit_html" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" mode="Transparent" x="20" y="8" width="301" height="10" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="8213d17a-5e7d-4fd2-81b2-509045752b80">
                        <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Left" markup="styled"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{label}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    <hyperlinkAnchorExpression><![CDATA[$F{label}]]></hyperlinkAnchorExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement style="Standard" x="321" y="8" width="30" height="10" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="1ced4974-5ea1-4ef1-86cb-dfd3fa5bd736">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="cm"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER} + $F{pageIndex} + 4]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <rectangle>
                    <reportElement stretchType="ContainerHeight" x="0" y="8" width="11" height="10" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" forecolor="#1BAEF7" backcolor="#56B4FC" uuid="ee55c1ea-8c69-45ae-86d8-6166dcddb18b">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="cm"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <graphicElement>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    </graphicElement>
                </rectangle>
            </frame>


        </frame>
        <frame>
            <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="362" y="0" width="340" height="17" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="d1247e47-59b4-4930-ad78-c76a0374f555">
                <property name="ShowOutOfBoundContent" value="false"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.FreeLayout"/>
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{level}  == 21]]></printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement stretchType="ContainerHeight" x="5" y="0" width="11" height="17" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" forecolor="#E8A435" backcolor="#FCCF3A" uuid="38bc71e5-6d69-4ab3-8a6b-0c1bba53a26c">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="cm"/>
                </reportElement>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </rectangle>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" hyperlinkType="LocalAnchor">
                <reportElement style="Standard" x="20" y="0" width="290" height="17" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="b19a02f7-3d3f-4086-86ed-5dc6859e5fd1"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{label}]]></textFieldExpression>
                <hyperlinkAnchorExpression><![CDATA[$F{label}]]></hyperlinkAnchorExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement key="" style="Standard" x="310" y="0" width="30" height="17" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="bc43bd36-7466-457c-95e6-384410c05cbe"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER} + $F{pageIndex} + 4]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </frame>
    </band>
</detail>
<pageFooter>
    <band height="31">
        <frame>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="702" height="31" uuid="ca4af90c-cc2f-406c-865f-59680b968139">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.HorizontalRowLayout"/>
            </reportElement>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement style="Fußzeile 8,5pt" x="0" y="0" width="351" height="31" uuid="c3e365c7-5dde-419e-a0da-950bf7d16710"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["© report: Quartalsbericht "+$P{Berichtsquartal}+" für Einrichtung "+$P{Einrichtungspseudonym}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" evaluationTime="Master">
                <reportElement style="Fußzeile 8,5pt" x="351" y="0" width="351" height="31" uuid="94da8446-69d3-4dc9-a791-d413082e42cc">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="cm"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{MASTER_CURRENT_PAGE} != null ? $V{MASTER_CURRENT_PAGE}+"/"+$V{MASTER_TOTAL_PAGES} : $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </frame>
    </band>
</pageFooter>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related to your first attempt, you have misunderstood how multiple columns page work.

You do not decided in which column the fields will go, by positioning them accordingly, instead jasper-report will break to next column based on `printOrder`, if vertical it will break when it hits end of page or finds a manual column break either through a group or a

```
<break type="Column">
    <reportElement x="0" y="15" width="100" height="1" uuid="c082e856-5507-4b0f-9dde-01b7fac85a4f"/>
</break>
```

## Using multiple columns with manual column break

This solution is feasible if you are sure that first part will fit in first column on the page, if it does not it will overflow in second column and the column break will lead to a page break,

The solution is to sort data and then either group as in example below or by adding a manual column break as above.

**Example** (using datasource from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36306170/5292302)), break to new column when reputation is less then 100.000

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="2columnsbreak" columnCount="2" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="277" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="81a13ec8-f22d-44f0-9335-c15e2fe28614">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="CVS"/>
    <queryString language="csv">
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="User" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Rep" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <group name="UserWithLowRep" isStartNewColumn="true">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[($F{Rep}<100000)]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="24" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField evaluationTime="Group" evaluationGroup="UserWithLowRep">
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="270" height="20" uuid="456c89e2-8e48-4e01-95ff-e56f2b150e0f"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($V{COLUMN_NUMBER}==1?"User with high rep":"User with low rep")]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="23" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="270" height="20" uuid="2daf5f8f-87a1-4f7e-b1de-2807811a1ddd"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{User}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

> The `groupExpression` will break to new column when it changes

**Output**

[image: example]

> **Note** How you can use the built-in variabile `$V{COLUMN_NUMBER}`, to output and format data as you like depending on column. In this example 2 columns it will either have value 1 (for data in first column) or 2 (for data in second column).