# How to identify the end of page while rendering the table?

Tags: jasper-reports

I am new to jasper world.
I want to render table on left and right side of page like...

```
Item Name     Item Price        Item Name     Item Price
Item1         20                Item11         40
Item2         30                Item12         10
Item3         40                Item13         30
.                               .
.                               .
Item10        30                Item20         30
<Here Page ends>                <Here Page ends Moved to next page>
```

I have created below simple code using Jaspersoft to render the table and its rendering properly, but I want to add **Continue..** text at the place of `<Here Page ends>` and `<Here Page ends Moved to next page>`.

```
<jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                <datasetRun subDataset="ItemDataSet" uuid="e335b742-7913-4832-93bc-8f211fc4c73f">
                    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{ItemDataSource}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                </datasetRun>
                <jr:column width="90" uuid="d5eb0cc8-2ae8-43fd-acfe-209e1948adef">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column1"/>
                    <jr:columnHeader style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30" uuid="1e5654a6-312f-4974-a84a-02d99741e6d5"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[Item Name]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30" uuid="e0af50c5-c6d2-4d10-8a03-656dd20a790a"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="100" uuid="1f5a81e4-5c5f-4044-a08b-659ffb3e4311">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column2"/>
                    <jr:columnHeader style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="be3258e1-1a01-4c19-818f-395a77b8c9d0"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[Item Price]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="ef399751-bba2-49d7-99d9-84bc93a1e50d"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{price}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
            </jr:table>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you have other components? Or only this table in your report? Hence is putting it in pageFooter enough?

Comment: @PetterFriberg Yes I have other components. Table is started from 2nd page of report. If I give it in pageFooter, what if table ends at left side then 'Countinue..' text will be get display at right side as well. Am I right?

Comment: You can use lastPageFooter to avoid it on last page and title band on first, but yeah if also other stuff is present you need a more complex solution

Comment: I have an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31562288/i-want-continue-text-when-sub-report-will-overflow-to-new-page that is a start but it will use a subreport